# What's the best way to compare two integer arrays and find the first to last difference?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Supposing two integer arrays nums and numsCopy,for example:

```
int[] nums = {2,5,3,8,6,10}
int[] numsCopy = {2,3,5,6,8,10}
```

I want to compare thus two arrays and finnd the first and the last different integers and recording their position and then count the length, what's the best way to do that?
using java.

Comment: Count the length of what?

Comment: using one iteration with two pointers: one that starts at the beginning and one that starts at the end (of each one of the aarays), both will move towards each other and will halt once either: a) both of them reached different elements, or b) once they've crossed

Comment: @dasblinkenlight count the length of the longest difference. for example, thee first different value is 5/3, and position is 1, and the last difference is 6/8, and then length is 4.

Comment: `best way to do that except use two iterations` please motivate looking for something that seems second best.

Comment: You can logically not do better than using two iterations, if by that you mean you go once from the right and once from the left until you find a difference, unless there's something special about the arrays that you're not telling us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is, of course, to use two iterations.  As @greybeard mentioned, we'd really like to know what is wrong with using two iterations.

Still, to answer the question, a possible way (by no means the best way), without using two `for` loops etc, would be to delegate the task to the Java9 stream API:

```
if (nums.length != numsCopy.length)
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arrays are not the same length");

IntPredicate elementsEqual = i -> nums[i] == numsCopy[i];
int first = IntStream.range(0, nums.length)
    .dropWhile(elementsEqual)
    .findFirst()
    .getAsInt();
int last = IntStream.iterate(nums.length - 1, i -> i >= first, i -> i - 1)
    .dropWhile(elementsEqual)
    .findFirst()
    .getAsInt();
int count = last - first + 1;
```

Throws `NoSuchElementException` if no differences are found.

If all you wanted was the length of the difference subsequence, you could do this in one stream statement:

```
long length = IntStream.iterate(nums.length - 1, i -> i >= 0, i -> i - 1)
    .dropWhile(elementsEqual)
    .limit(1)
    .flatMap(end -> IntStream.rangeClosed(0, end))
    .dropWhile(elementsEqual)
    .count();
```

This returns the length of the required subsequence, or 0 if the arrays match.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two for loops, if both arrays have the same size. One starting at the start one at the end:

```
int start;
for (start = 0; start < nums.length; start++) {
  if (nums[start] != numsCopy[start])
     break;
}
if (start == nums.length)
  return; // there are no different entries

int end;
for (end = nums.length - 1; end >= 0; end--) {
  if (nums[end] != numsCopy[end])
     break;
}
// the distance of the first to the last entry
int dist = end - start;
// the count of elements in the rang from first to last
int count = dist + 1;
```

This code would exit early at the `return` if there are no differences in the two arrays. If there is exactly one difference `count` would be `1`. In your example the `count` would be `4`. Generally, `count` is between `1` and `nums.length`.

Here is a compact *(and possibly more efficient)* version using while loops and reducing the number of tests like *greybeard* suggested in the comments. The result *(early exit or value in `count`)* is exactly the same as in the above more verbose version.

```
int start = 0;
while (nums[start] == numsCopy[start]) {
  if (++start == nums.length)
     return; // there are no different entries
}
int end = nums.length - 1;
while (nums[end] == numsCopy[end]) end--;
int count = end - start + 1;
```

Comment: I’d stop the second loop when I got to `start == end`.  Oh, and I’d start at `length-1` to avoid the array index exception.

Comment: @AJNeufeld But how do you know if there was one or non different entries? The second point is true, thanks.

Comment: If `start == nums.length`, there are no different entries.  And if the second loop runs while `end > start`, since `end` would start at `length-1`, `count` would actually be -1 when there are no differences.

Comment: Looks like OP wants `end - start + 1`, so count would be zero when there are no differences, and one with exactly one difference.

Comment: @AJNeufeld That's a good point, but I prefer to keep the loop simple. However, I used your suggestion to add an early exit case. Now end could never exceed start. **Edit:** I also thought about that `+1` thing and added it.

Comment: `Now end could never exceed start` so why does the second loop still have two terminating conditions? It just needs `!=`. Similarly, terminate the first loop on `!=`, and return on `start == nums.length` *in the first loop*.

Comment: @greybeard Good suggestion, but still I prefer to keep it simple, but I used your suggestion to add a second version implementing it.

Answer (score -1):

1) Get size of 1st array .
 2) Get size of 2nd array.
 3) Run the loop for the smallest of two.
 4) Compare each array store the result.